# Can't access to localhost

Tags: php, mysql, apache, localhost, http-status-code-403

I was working on a project yesterday in the localhost, and everything was fine, i could acces with no problem. But today, when i try to open any file of my webpage or access to localhost, i get

```
403 Forbbiden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
```

The weird par is that I actually can acces to localhost/phpmyadmin

The Apache error log says this:

```
[Sun May 25 14:18:04.111705 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4996:tid 396] AH00455:
Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 25 14:18:04.268714 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4996:tid 396] AH00456: Apache     Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:13:13
[Sun May 25 14:18:04.268714 2014] [core:notice] [pid 4996:tid 396] AH00094: Command     line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d     C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Sun May 25 14:18:04.273714 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4996:tid 396] AH00418:     Parent: Created child process 1152
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/wamp/vhost] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/wamp/vhost] does not exist
```

Comment: you are probably missing the permission to the folder try giving 775 permission to the folder.

Comment: You misconfigured all document roots of the vhosts.  If you're running that server, reconfigure the vhosts. If you have no clue what is going on, have you tried turning it off and on again? If that didn't help, reinstall wamp.

Comment: @hakre Thank you, i tried to reconfigure the vhost, but it make everything worse, so i re-installes wamp and it works now, thank you. I think, learning is better if you first messed everything up.

Comment: Hint: Put your configuration files under version control. Then you can compare what you changed and you can better spot where you've introduced the error. http://git-scm.com/